# Solving general two-dimensional recurrence relation

Tags: co.combinatorics

Any techniques for deriving a closed form solution for the following recurrence relation? Or bounds on asymptotic behavior for large $n$?

$$a_{n+1,k} = \sum_{0 \le i \le n} \frac{n!}{i!} a_{i,k-1}$$

where $n,k \ge 0$ and $a_{0,0} = 0$

Comment: You will need more boundary conditions; I'm guessing you'll want to set $a_{n, 0}$.

Comment: For fixed $r > 1$, if you set $a_{r-1,0} = 1$ and $a_{n,0} =0$ for $n\neq r$ then I believe the solution is given by the $r$-Stirling numbers $a_{n,k}=\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ k+1 \end{array}\right]_r$. See Broder, "The r-Stirling numbers" (1984).